# Casting the return of objectAtIndex on NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, casting, nsarray

Trying to cast the return of objectAtIndex.

```
(MyClass *)[myArray objectAtIndex:1].name;
```

Can you cast inline like this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
((MyClass *)[myArray objectAtIndex:1]).name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid casting altogether by replacing the dot-syntax of accessing properties with the regular method invocation syntax:

```
[[myArray objectAtIndex:1] name]
```

Comment: That will throw a warning though, and if you compile with ARC I think it may change to an error.

Comment: Yes this is a bad idea even if you are okay with the warning, if you remove the property `name` from `MyClass` you will continue to get a warning, but your app will crash and the code is hard to maintain this way...

Comment: @graver There's never a warning when you use this syntax: it's either an error, or a warning-free compile. When the identifier `name` does not correspond to a selector supported by any `@interface` in the system, an error is triggered. This approach works beautifully most of the time, and is a small price to pay for avoiding the need to provide an explicit cast.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight what you're saying is **only** valid when you're using ARC. I suppose you haven't developed apps prior ios5...

Comment: @graver Turning ARC off does not alter this behavior of the compiler: you do not get a warning when the identifier matches a selector of *some* object in the system, and you get an error when it does not match. I suppose there may be a bug in the compiler prior to LLVM that produces a warning, but that is not a good reason to avoid a perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I don't say the syntax is incorrect, just is error prone. Here is an example, except for `MyClass` that has a property `name` you have another class `MyClass2` that also has name property, then you import both of the files to the class where you are using `[[myArray objectAtIndex:1] name]` and remove the `name` property from `MyClass` - you won't get a compilation error neither a warning, but in runtime your app will crash with `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: @graver I understand that this approach is based entirely on the compiler's guess, but in practice it tends to work reasonably fine: apart from very common identifiers, such as `name`, your selectors are often either system-wide unique, or so basic that you do not bother to remove or rename them. Of course there are situations when this breaks apart, causing runtime errors, but Xcode provides you with a full-text search and other refactoring tools that help you avoid the most common mistakes on renaming or removing an identifier.